# What does L.D F0, 0(R1) mean?

Tags: assembly, mips

[image]

What does the following MIPS instruction in the listing above mean?

```
L.D  F0, 0(R1)
```

The book where the snippet is taken is "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach", by Hennesey & Patterson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load [double precision floating-point (64-bit) data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) into register [`f0`](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-31/ass31_2.html) from the [address in register `R1`](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs350/addressing/addsclm.html).

The rest of code is well commented, it's a simple loop through an array of doubles whose size is in `r2` and that add to each element the number in `f2`.

The presence of the `daddui` (Double Add Unsigned Immediate) indicates the presence of the [MIPS64 ISA](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MIPS_Architecture_MIPS64_InstructionSet_%20AFP_P_MD00087_06.05.pdf).